# Trying to sending this multi-part SOAP request with an attachment to a web service

Tags: c#, .net, soap, webrequest, mtom

I am trying to hit a SOAP-based, MTOM service which accepts multipart attachment. Here is how I create the request from C#:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("...skipping URL...");
request.ContentType = @"multipart/related;charset=""UTF-8"";type=""application/xop+xml"";start=""<http://tempuri.org/0>"";boundary=""uuid:f276e990-75d0-4b5d-a0fd-e00a096e30ce+id=1"";start-info=""application/soap+xml""";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 30000;
request.Headers.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

var postData = @"--uuid:f276e990-75d0-4b5d-a0fd-e00a096e30ce+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type=""text/xml""

[Skipping the SOAP envelope that goes here...]

--uuid:f276e990-75d0-4b5d-a0fd-e00a096e30ce+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636875796573424479>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sample.pdf")) + @"

--uuid:f276e990-75d0-4b5d-a0fd-e00a096e30ce+id=1--";

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    writer.Write(postData);
```

My question is this: Since I know the content type must be application/octet-stream and the transfer encoding must be binary, am I correctly reading the binary data of my PDF file for submission to this service? Is it correct to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sample.pdf"))` here or is it incorrect? How should I create the request to send the attachment?

**Edit**: Would it be more correct to do something like this?

```
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var attachment = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sample.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    writer.Write(postDataPrefix); // Add everything up to the start of the attachment binary. 
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Flush();
    attachment.CopyTo(stream); // Add the actual attachment binary.
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Flush();
    writer.Write(postDataSuffix); // Add everything after the attachment binary.
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Flush();
}
```

Comment: You are using http so you should be using a Base 64 string not UTF8.

Comment: @jdweng I can't assume the server supports base 64, the only thing I know is that it supports binary octet streams. Its kind of like a black box to me.

Comment: http attachments are always base 64 strings according to the specification.  The server must support base 64.  It is really the same as GZIP.

Comment: @jdweng This is a SOAP + MTOM server. It works differently, like this -> https://www.crcind.com/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSOAP_mtom Binary data can be placed into separate MIME parts without base-64 encoding

Comment: It is only supported with chunking mode which is http 1.1 (not stream http 1.0).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Comment: @jdweng By the way, I want to say thanks for your help so far. So, right now I am wondering how to craft such a request. I am wondering if toggling SendChunked on would be enough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.sendchunked?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Not sure. I usually use :  request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

Comment: @jdweng It looks like it defaults to version 1.1 but I have enforced Version11 like you suggested. So, it looks like I am able to write to the POST stream with the contents of the binary file like I have in my edit. I am wondering if this is correctly RFC compliant as its a straight up binary octet stream as far as I can see.

Comment: The client and server negotiate operating mode by using comparing header in the webpage and the headers in the request to get a common operating mode.  With the server set to 1.1 it defaults to 1.1 unless the client requests 1.0 to be backwards compatible.  A server that is set to 1.0 normally cannot be set to 1.1.  So the server may not allow Binary Mode if it is older and is only 1.0 compatible.  I assume you mean the client defaults to 1.0.  You either have to look at the response to see if server support 1.1 or look at the server source html data.

Comment: @jdweng I don't see anywhere that it says you need chunking for this, do you? I'm pretty sure MTOM does not require chunking at all.

Comment: Look again at your link that shows http 1.1 : https://www.crcind.com/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSOAP_mtom

Comment: @jdweng Its not required, though. You can chunk your request if you want, but its up to you. For example, check these payloads: https://docs.axway.com/bundle/APIGateway_762_PolicyDevFilterReference_allOS_en_HTML5/page/Content/PolicyDevTopics/conversion_insert_mtom.htm

Comment: So have you actually tested your code? Does it work properly? And how can we test soap mtom server, is there any test server online?

Comment: Have you considered using WCF? That way you would be able to do this in a couple of lines of code. Just import the WSDL and shoot. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming).